# Free memory of all json_objects from root (including root)

Tags: c, json-c

I have this code:

```
    struct json_object* parsed_json;
    struct json_object* portInConfig;
    struct json_object* masterInConfig;
    struct json_object* mapInConfig;
    struct json_object* managerPasswdInConfig;
    struct json_object* adminPasswdInConfig;
    struct json_object* modPasswdInConfig;
    struct json_object* guardPasswdInConfig;
    struct json_object* trustedPasswdInConfig;
    struct json_object* serverNameInConfig;
    struct json_object* team1NameInConfig;
    struct json_object* team2NameInConfig;
    struct json_object* team1ColorInConfig;
    struct json_object* team2ColorInConfig;
    struct json_object* gamemodeInConfig;

    parsed_json = json_object_from_file("config.json");
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "port", &portInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find port number in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "master", &masterInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find master variable in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "map", &mapInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find map name in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "manager_password", &managerPasswdInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find manager password in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "admin_password", &adminPasswdInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find admin password in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "moderator_password", &modPasswdInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find moderator password in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "guard_password", &guardPasswdInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find guard password in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "trusted_password", &trustedPasswdInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find trusted password in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "server_name", &serverNameInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find server name in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "team1_name", &team1NameInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find team1 name in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "team2_name", &team2NameInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find team2 name in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "team1_color", &team1ColorInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find team1 color in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "team2_color", &team2ColorInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find team2 color in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if (json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "gamemode", &gamemodeInConfig) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to find gamemode in config\n");
        return -1;
    }
    port                      = json_object_get_int(portInConfig);
    master                    = json_object_get_int(masterInConfig);
    const char* managerPasswd = json_object_get_string(managerPasswdInConfig);
    const char* adminPasswd   = json_object_get_string(adminPasswdInConfig);
    const char* modPasswd     = json_object_get_string(modPasswdInConfig);
    const char* guardPasswd   = json_object_get_string(guardPasswdInConfig);
    const char* trustedPasswd = json_object_get_string(trustedPasswdInConfig);
    char*       serverName    = (char*) json_object_get_string(serverNameInConfig);
    char*       team1Name     = (char*) json_object_get_string(team1NameInConfig);
    char*       team2Name     = (char*) json_object_get_string(team2NameInConfig);
    uint8       team1Color[3];
    uint8       team2Color[3];
    uint8       gamemode = json_object_get_int(gamemodeInConfig);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        team1Color[i] = json_object_get_int(json_object_array_get_idx(team1ColorInConfig, i));
        team2Color[i] = json_object_get_int(json_object_array_get_idx(team2ColorInConfig, i));
    }
    uint8 mapArrayLen = json_object_array_length(mapInConfig);
    char  mapArray[mapArrayLen][64];

    for (int i = 0; i < mapArrayLen; ++i) {
        uint8 stringLen = json_object_get_string_len(json_object_array_get_idx(mapInConfig, i));
        if (stringLen > 64) {
            continue;
        }
        memcpy(mapArray[i], json_object_get_string(json_object_array_get_idx(mapInConfig, i)), stringLen + 1);
    }

    json_object_put(parsed_json);
```

The issue im facing is that when i try to free the parsed_json object
it doesnt free all of objects.

If i have this in while loop valgrind would yell that im freeing memory
i shoudlnt.

What is the way to free all the objects (No memory leak) while not freeing memory i shoudlnt be freeing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually doesnt have any memory leak.

The issue was in the way i stored the string.
When passing it to a function it didnt free the memory anymore.

Comment: In a few days, if you can, please come back and mark this as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yep i can do so tomorrow.